# Why does QImage load a 24-bit BMP to get a QImage bit depth of 32 bits?

Tags: c++, bmp, qt6

I'm trying to implement the Huffman algorithm to compress the pixel part of a BMP file through Qt. But `QImage` seems to be converted to 32-bit after loading 24-bit BMP. The data I got through the `bits()` method is also 32-bit, which makes the data used for compression different from the original data. Does this mean that I should manually process BMP image files?

The Qt kit version I am using is `Desktop Qt 6.4.1 MinGW 64-bit`.

I have tried:

- Save the 32-bit BMP loaded into QImage directly with the save method, and the resulting BMP is 24-bit.

```cpp
QImage image;
image.load("example.bmp");
image.save("example2.bmp");
```

- Load 24-bit BMP to QImage, check its bit depth and format, the result is 32-bit.

```cpp
QImage image;
image.load("example2.bmp");
unsigned short bitCount = image.depth();
QImage::Format format = image.format();
```

- After reading the 24-bit BMP into QImage and converting it to 24-bit, the subsequent operations are as expected.

```cpp
QImage image;
image.load("example2.bmp");
image = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);
image.save("example3.bmp");
```

I expect that the bit depth and data loaded by QImage should be consistent with the original file.

Comment: Image processing libraries, like Qt, will often use a single internal representation model and convert all image files, be they bmp, gif, jpg, png, and others to it. Without looking at what QImage does, it is not unreasonable to end up with an RGBA data, i.e., an alpha channel, after loading an image.